# Why does my 2d image change size when displaying using ARKit?

Tags: swift, arkit

Im trying to display this square on a horizontal plane in ARKit but the square is a different size and shape every-time it detects a horizontal  plane. How could I make it so that the 2d square that Im trying to display is the same size and shape?

I tried using physicalSize object but that didnt seem to work for my problem.

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor) -> SCNNode? {

    let size = planes.count
    if size > 0 {
        return nil
    }

    // creating SCNNode that we are going to return
    let ARAnchorNode = SCNNode()

    // converting the ARAnchor to an ARPlaneAnchor to get access to ARPlaneAnchor's extent and center values
    let anchor = anchor as? ARPlaneAnchor

    // creating plane geometry
    planeNode.geometry = SCNPlane(width: CGFloat((anchor?.extent.x)!), height: CGFloat((anchor?.extent.z)!))

    // transforming node
    planeNode.position = SCNVector3((anchor?.center.x)!, 0, (anchor?.center.z)!)
    planeNode.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIImage(named: "boxone")
    planeNode.eulerAngles = SCNVector3(-Float.pi/2,0,0)
    sceneView.debugOptions = []

    // adding plane node as child to ARAnchorNode due to mandatory ARKit conventions
    ARAnchorNode.addChildNode(planeNode)

    //returning ARAnchorNode (must return a node from this function to add it to the scene)
    planes.append(planeNode)

    return ARAnchorNode
}
```

I want the image that im trying to display to be the same size and shape every time I try to display in the real world.

Answer (score 0):

Added this line of code to make the image the same size everytime I display it in the ARKit environment.

```
//creates a box where node will appear
    planeNode.geometry = SCNBox(width: 0.5, height: 0.5, length: 0, chamferRadius: 0)
```